# Fetch failed on Docker, but works fine locally

Tags: node.js, typescript, docker, node-fetch

I have the following simple Node app:

```
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { Client, GatewayIntentBits } from "discord.js";

dotenv.config();

const client = new Client({
    intents: [
        GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
        GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers,
        GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent
    ]
});

client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN);

client.on("messageCreate", async (message) => {
    if (message.channelId === "1202421002513158225") {
        console.log(process.env.CK_API_KEY);
        try {
            const rawResponse = await fetch(
                "http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/notifications/push",
                {
                    headers: {
                        "Api-Key": process.env.CK_API_KEY,
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({
                        body: {
                            id: "65f387af217854a638ae3bf3",
                            text: message.content
                        }
                    }),
                    method: "POST"
                }
            );

            const response = await rawResponse.json();
            console.info(response)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }
});
```

It runs fine locally but when running it with `docker run` it throws an error:

```
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:13737:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async Client.<anonymous> (file:///index.ts:1:437) {
  [cause]: Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3000
      at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1605:16) {
    errno: -111,
    code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    syscall: 'connect',
    address: '127.0.0.1',
    port: 3000
  }
```

Here is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:21.7.1

WORKDIR /

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npx", "tsx", "index.ts" ]
```

My `package.json`:

```
{
    "name": "commerce-karma-notify",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Push notifications from the Commerce Karma Discord Server in the updates channel to the Commerce Karma Notification Center.",
    "main": "index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --exec npm run on",
        "on": "npx tsx index.ts",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "format:check": "prettier --check .",
        "format:write": "prettier --write .",
        "lint:check": "eslint .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
        "typescript": "^5.4.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "tsx": "^4.7.1"
    }
}
```

I've tried changing the url to my ip address. Still no luck. I'm using Docker locally. Any reason why this is not working. Please keep in mind I am new to Docker.

I'm using:

- Docker 25.0.3
- Node 21.7.1 (on my machine and on my Docker image)
- node-fetch 3.3.2
- TypeScript 5.4.2
- MacOS Sonoma 14.4

## To reproduce

1. Create a Next.js app `npx creat-next-app@latest`

   a. Create a folder inside of `app` named `/api/test`

   b. Create a `route.ts|js` file with the following content:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";

export async function GET (request: Request) {
    return NextResponse.json ({test: "Test"})
}
```

2. Create a new Node.js app `npm init -y`

   a. Include the following package.json, tsconfig.json, and Dockerfile:

```
{
    "main": "index.ts",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "nodemon --exec npm run on",
        "on": "npx tsx index.ts",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "format:check": "prettier --check .",
        "format:write": "prettier --write .",
        "lint:check": "eslint .",
        "lint:fix": "eslint --fix ."
    },
    "type": "module",
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "discord.js": "^14.14.1",
        "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
        "node-fetch": "^3.3.2",
        "typescript": "^5.4.2"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^7.2.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^7.2.0",
        "eslint": "^8.57.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.1.0",
        "prettier": "^3.2.5",
        "tsx": "^4.7.1"
    }
}
```

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "inlineSources": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**/*"
  ]
}
```

```
FROM node:21.7.1

WORKDIR /

COPY package.json package.json
COPY package-lock.json package-lock.json

RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD [ "npx", "tsx", "index.ts" ]
```

```
c. Create a file called `index.ts` with the following content:
```

```
const main = async () => {
            try {
                const rawResponse = await fetch(
                    "https://localhost:3000/api/test");
                
                
    
                const response = await rawResponse.json();
                console.info(response)
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }

        main()
```

3. Build and run the app with Docker

Comment: "127.0.0.1" is separate for each container.

Comment: You have the URL `http://127.0.0.1:3000` hard-coded in your application; what is it supposed to reach?

Comment: Are you trying to reach the host machine using the localhost address?

Comment: @David Maze  It is an API endpoint with Next.js I have on the computer that I'm running Docker desktop on.

Comment: @0xts Yes it's on the same computer running Docker desktop.

Comment: @Ethan you'll have to bind the host network with the docker using `host.docker.internal:host-gateway`. Read more [here](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host).

Comment: @0xts This doesn't seem to be the problem. I tried port forwarding the local address and I still get the same error when fetching to the port forwarded address on my Docker image

Comment: @Ethan if you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), I'd be able to replicate and see the issue myself to help out.

Comment: @0xts I added all of the steps to the question

Comment: Are both the NextJS app and your Node app running in containers? You can create a docker network, attach each of them to that network, then use the hostname of the Next app as the url in the Node app. Running them both with docker compose is probably easier.

Comment: @J. Titus No. The Next.js app is not a Docker container.